# AvaloniaUI - Equivalent of CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, collectionviewsource, avaloniaui, avalonia, listcollectionview

We like to migrate our WPF-App to AvaloniaUI and stumble over a couple of CollectionViewSource entries:

```
       <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedMethods" Source="{Binding Methods}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Group" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>

            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Group" Direction="Descending" />
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
```

CollectionViewSources are quite great, since the ViewModel has no WPF-Code and can be reused with other UI frameworks.

Is there a way to do Grouping/Sorting/Filtering on ObservableCollections in AvaloniaUI in a WPF-Like approach?

Comment: There is DynamicData, but that will carry Rx dependency with it, not sure how that would affect your "reused in other UI frameworks" requirement.